# There is no internet connection after installing ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, 20.04, internet

I have just installed ubuntu 20.04 on a desktop pc with wired connection, and there is not internet connection. I tried out these commands:

```
sudo mv /etc/netplan/*.yaml  /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml
sudo nano /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml   
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens33:
      dhcp4: true
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
ping google.com
ping: connect: Network is unreachable
```

I also tried a few ethernets interfaces as enp0s5, enp0s4.

I am still facing the same problem.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema could you please check "Screenshot 1"

Comment: Please don't put screenshots of the `terminal`. Always copy the text from the terminal and paste directly into the question. Then format the pasted text as `code` using the {_} icon above the edit window.

Comment: @user68186 OP doesn't have Internet access on the target computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml...

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml
```

And make it look like this...

<strike>For a Ubuntu server installation:</strike>

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: true
```

For a Ubuntu desktop installation:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

`sudo netplan generate`

`sudo netplan apply`

`reboot`

**Note**: For a Ubuntu desktop installation, use the Network GUI to set up your connection.

You also need to check your ethernet cable, as it's only showing 100Mbit link speed. The hub/switch/router/modem also has to support 1Gbit speed.

**Update #1:**

Was not getting an IPv4 address from the router, and only had a 100Mbit link speed. Did one of the following...

- replaced the ethernet cable
- re-seated the original ethernet cable

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133916/discussion-on-answer-by-heynnema-there-is-no-internet-connection-after-installin).